# App Store Rejection for external Subscriptions: Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Our iOS app was rejected from App Review because we require an external subscription. We already went through the initial back and forth with a reviewer to determine whether it's allowed and that part was approved.

However, now the app review comes back with this:

> Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We were unable to locate some of the features described in your metadata. Specifically,  “this application requires a paid subscription”.

I can't find any setting that matches anything related to external subscriptions. Anybody know what key needs to be set?

Comment: Is the need for a subscription written in your app description?

Comment: Can you share your app on TestFlight? It’s almost certainly related to how you word your app text description and not the build. I would look at how [Netflix describes their in app purchase and subscription model](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/netflix/id363590051)